# Django saving data to wrong fields

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

When I create an object in Django it saves the data to the wrong fields. When I make the following postman request:

[image]

The return serialized data is correct. But the data saved to the db is not which looks like:
[image]

The first two fields are correct but the rest are not. It saves the price as the rating, the weight_unit as the price, the user id as the weight and the rating as the user_is.

#### View

```
class CoffeeViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):
  def create(self, request):
    serializer = CoffeeSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        c = Coffee.objects.create(
            company = serializer.validated_data.get('company'),
            rating = serializer.validated_data.get('rating'),
            weight = serializer.validated_data.get('weight'),
            weight_unit = serializer.validated_data.get('weight_unit'),
            blend = serializer.validated_data.get('blend'),
            price = serializer.validated_data.get('price'),
            user = request.user
        )
        print(c)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_401_BAD_REQUEST)
```

#### Serializer

```
class CoffeeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Coffee
        fields = ['company', 'blend', 'rating', 'price', 'weight_unit', 'weight']
```

also when I print validated_data is correct so my assumption is something with how the object is saved is not correct but I can not figure out.

#### validated data

```
OrderedDict([('company', 'Stumptown'), ('blend', 'Hair Bender'), ('rating', 7), ('price', Decimal('16.00')), ('weight_unit', 'OZ'), ('weight', Decimal('12.00'))])
```

#### Model

```
class Coffee(models.Model):
    company = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    blend = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rating = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    OUNCE = 'OZ'
    GRAM = 'GR'
    POUND = 'LB'
    KILOGRAM = 'KG'
    WEIGHT_UNIT_CHOICES = [
        (OUNCE, 'Ounce'),
        (GRAM, 'Gram'),
        (POUND, 'Pound'),
        (KILOGRAM, 'Kilogram'),
    ]
    weight_unit = models.CharField(
        max_length=2,
        choices=WEIGHT_UNIT_CHOICES,
        default=GRAM,
    )
    weight = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What is going on here?

Comment: Can't see an issue with your code. Might be an issue with how you are inspecting the database table? Can you share the model

Comment: Sure added above.

Comment: How are you inspecting the data in the DB?

Comment: Yeah thats what the screenshot above is of

Comment: But **how** is that table generated in the screenshot? I think whatever query you have used to generate it is incorrect

Comment: There is no query, thats default view for sqlite db viewer which is equalivent to select * from table. Plus I feel like a query wouldn't cause fields to be misplaced unless you doing some sort of merge

Comment: I am going to uninstall the db viewer and reinstall it. I feel like the problem has to lie with that and not my code.